# Rich man sells his brain to "demon" alien

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

A very rich man summons an alien (who is in his bathtub) to make a deal. The man has figured out that it is not magic. He trades some technology or knowledge for his brain at death. The brain goes into a giant hive mind computer, but later the mans brain takes over the computer. I think it might have been by a female author.

Comment: This is a decent start, but please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if the questions there prompt more detail, which you can answer into your question to help us help you.

Comment: I've read this in an anthology.

Comment: Thanks you! I vaguely recalled it was written by the wife of a famous writer under a pseudonym, and this certainly fits that.

Answer (score 8):

I've found the anthology, and the story.

This is *[Positively the Last Pact With - The Devil?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50384)*, by Janet Asimov writing as J. O. Jeppson.

Comment: [Obligatory Archive.org link](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v050n03_1976-03/page/n49/mode/2up)